# In Cassandra why create two tables for users to search by username and email instead of adding an index?

Tags: cassandra, cql, nosql

Reading this article: [Basic Rules of Cassandra Data Modeling](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling) they say, if you want to be able to query users by both email and username, you should make two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users_by_username (
    username text PRIMARY KEY,
    email text,
    age int
)

CREATE TABLE users_by_email (
    email text PRIMARY KEY,
    username text,
    age int
)
```

Why would you do this? Doesn't it make the data much less manageable for such a small thing? Why wouldn't you just do one table and have an index?

```
-- A table holding the user info
CREATE TABLE users (
    username text,
    email text,
    age int,
    PRIMARY KEY((username),email)
);

-- An index that gives good performance on email searching
CREATE INDEX user_email ON users (email);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You should make two table because of high cardinality issue in index**

> If you create an index on a high-cardinality column, which has many distinct values, a query between the fields will incur many seeks for very few results. In the table with a billion emails, looking up user by email (a value that is typically unique for each user) is likely to be very inefficient.

**When you execute query with email, cassandra will execute this query on every node, each node will look up it's local index and send the response. Your merge result will be a single user. You are querying on every node to get a single result, it's very inefficient**

Instead if you create a separate table for user by email. And execute query, cassandra only need to look up into a single node by the partition key email.

Or If you are using cassandra version 3.0 or higher you could use [Materialized Views](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-in-cassandra-3-0-materialized-views) that will maintain your denormalization automatically.

Source : http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_when_use_index_c.html

Comment: So, how would you keep both (or possibly 3 or 4 tables) all in sync? Is it just extra code in the business logic to update each table on any change? Can JPA handle this automatically?

Comment: You can use [Batch](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlBatch.html) to acheive atomicity.

Comment: If you are using cassandra version 3.0 or higher you could use Materialized Views that will maintain your denormalization automatically.

Comment: Thank you. Aren't Materialized views slower write though?

Comment: Thank you. one additional question: with multiple tables like this, is there any way to use JPA? Or is that not possible since an entity is mapped to one representation of the data (AFAIK)?